# AJAX Cascading DropDown JavaScript event onready

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'd like to fire a JavaScript function when AJAX returns the values of drop down items.

The scenario is:

function 1 fires -> ajax gets items from database -> the dropdown items are filles -> my javascript function is called.

Does any of you have idea how to make a handler for such event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, I'll show you a jQuery solution:

```
$.post("someScript.php", function(data) {
    /*This callback function is executed when the AJAX call returns successfully
    You would do something with your dropdown items here
    and then call your next function.*/
});
```

The various jQuery AJAX methods (`post`, `get`, `load` for example) all provide a way to pass a callback as an argument. The callback is executed upon a successful response from the server. Inside that callback function you can execute whatever code you need to, to deal with `data` which contains the response.

If you're not using jQuery, I'll assume you already have an `XMLHttpRequest` object. `XMLHttpRequest` has a property called `onreadystatechange` to which you can assign a function that runs when the state changes:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
        //This will be reached if the call returns successfully
    }
}
```

The idea is the same as the jQuery method shown above.